iFrame only showing half of the content
Attempting to plug a bandcamp iframe into a nextjs boilerplate.
Base.tsx
import { Meta } from '../layout/Meta';
import { AppConfig } from '../utils/AppConfig';
import { Banner } from './Banner';
import { Footer } from './Footer';
import { Hero } from './Hero';
import { Sponsors } from './Sponsors';
import { VerticalFeatures } from './VerticalFeatures';

const Base = () => (
  <div className="text-gray-600 antialiased">
    <Meta title={AppConfig.title} description={AppConfig.description} />
    <Hero />
    <Sponsors />
    <VerticalFeatures />
    <Banner />
    <Footer />
  </div>
);

export { Base };


Hero.tsx
Hero.tsx
import Link from 'next/link';
import { Background } from '../background/Background';
import { Button } from '../button/Button';
import { HeroOneButton } from '../hero/HeroOneButton';
import { Section } from '../layout/Section';
import { NavbarTwoColumns } from '../navigation/NavbarTwoColumns';
import { Logo } from './Logo';
import InstagramLogo from '../components/InstagramLogo.tsx';
import Player from '../components/Player.tsx'
import Iframe from 'react-iframe'

const Hero = () => (
  <Background color="bg-primary-800">
    <Section yPadding="py-6">
      <NavbarTwoColumns logo={<Logo xl />}>
        <li>
          <Link href="https://linktr.ee/olhar_band" target="_blank">
            Listen
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="https://olhar.bandcamp.com/album/smoke-2" target="_blank">
          Join Bandcamp</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="https://www.instagram.com/olhar_band/" target="_blank">
            <InstagramLogo />
          </Link>
        </li>
      </NavbarTwoColumns>
    </Section>

    <Section yPadding="pt-20 pb-32">
      <HeroOneButton
        title={
          <>
            {/*enter leading text{''}*/}
            <span className="text-golden-100">Welcome to where the eye meets
              the heart
            </span>
          </>
        }
      />
    </Section>
    <span>
        <Iframe
           style="border: 0; width: 350px; height: 588px;"
           src="https://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=3456052307/size=large/bgcol=333333/linkcol=e99708/transparent=true/"
           seamless>
           <a href="https://olhar.bandcamp.com/album/smoke-2">
              Smoke by Olhar
           </a>
        </Iframe>
      </span>
    <Section >

    </Section>
  </Background>
);

export { Hero };


I tried to embed an Iframe into a Hero.tsx file within a <span>. The Media showed and the audio played, but only half of it was visible. This is on Next.JS with Typescript. I'm using the boilerplate https://github.com/ixartz/Next-js-Boilerplate
enter image description here
